# Correct Trayakshar Mrityunjaya mantra

Tags: shiva, mantras

Which is the correct Trayakshar Mrityunjaya Mantra- Om Haum Joom Sah OR Om Joom Sah

Comment: @Rickross the first one is not three lettered but I read in one book that it is Trayakshar Mrityunjaya mantra. Maybe Om is put because in every mantra Om is put to increase its power. The second mantra I found on internet which they say is the Trayakshar Mrityunjaya mantra. So not sure which is the true Trayakshar Mrityunjaya mantra

Comment: Although u hv asked only abt the 3-lettered Mrityunjaya mantra I hv also given the long version (12-lettered) of the same

Comment: @Rickross ok thanks. The answer looks correct to me. I don't understand why people put wrong mantras in book. I don't want to name the book. But it has rishi name, Dhyan mantra of the mantra Om Haum Joom Sah.

Comment: Okay u can come to our chat room whn u hv spare time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct Tryakshara Mrityunjaya Mantra is Om jum sah, the 2nd one you gave.

Sarva Devadevi Mantra Koshah (Mantras collected from Tantras for all deities-complied by Upendranath Mukhopadhyaya) gives the following Mantra:

> Atha mrityunjaya mantrah:
>
> TAram sthirA sakarnendu bhriguhusarga samnvitah |
>  **TryakshAratmA
>   nigadito mrityunjaytmakah ||**
>
> Om jum sah || (1)

The Mantra first is given in a code (as is usual in Tantras).

Some hints to decode it are as follows:

TAram - TAraka Mantra or Om.

Sthira - referring to the letter Ja.

Bhrighu - referring to the letter Sa.

Sarga - Visarga (:)

The 1st Mantra that you gave is not given in the book under Shiva Mantras. So, it may or may not be a valid Mantra. But, whatever might be the case, it is not a 3-lettered Mantra. It is 4-lettered as you can see.

The text also gives another form of the Mrityunjaya Mantra which is not 3 but 12-lettered:

> Mrityunjayam samucchArya pAlaya dvitayam vadet |
>  Mrityunjayam
>   samucchArya punareva vilomatah ||
>  DwAdashAksharam mantrohayam
>   mrityunjayAbhidhoparah ||
>
> Om jum sah pAlaya pAlaya sah jum Om || (2)